# Aggregate the column values and keep the values greater than certain number

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Given a dataframe looks like this:

```
Unique_id  Value
105590  0.000627
105590  0.000650
105590  0.000648
105590  0.000650
......  ........
......  ........
106690  0.000652
106690  0.000634
106690  0.000632
```

There are unique_ids and every id has 288 values (rows)

- I only need to keep the unique id,s whose aggregate of 288 values are greater than 15 and less 20.

I have tried this

```
df3 = df.groupby('Unique_id').sum().reset_index()
```

but it only aggregate the values of unique ids.

How can this be done?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
df.groupby("Unique_id").filter(lambda x: (x["Value"].sum()>15)&(x["Value"].sum()<20))
```

Answer (score 2):

If need filter aggregated values use [`Series.between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html):

```
s = df.groupby("Unique_id")["Value"].sum()

df1 = s[s.between(15, 20)].reset_index(name='summed')
```

If need filter original DataFrame faster way use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) and then filter original DataFrame:

```
df2 = df[df.groupby("Unique_id")["Value"].transform('sum').between(15, 20)]
```